# How to disable a block in grapesjs?

Tags: block, grapesjs

I have a custom block and I need to disable it from being dragged and dropped after it has been used once.I came across only the option to disable a block entirely when it is first added.I am looking for a situation,when it can be used only once and then the block should be disabled.Any suggestions?
My code as of now,
editor.BlockManager.add('block',
{
id: 'block',
label: 'Block',
category: 'Basic',
//disable:true
})
and I am looking for something like,
editor.BlockManager.add('block',
{
id: 'block',
label: 'Block',
category: 'Basic',
if(is_enabled===false)
{
disable:false
}
else
{
disable:true
}
})

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding a event listener on load and update:

```
editor.value = grapesjs.init(options)

...

editor.value.on('load update', result => {
  const html = editor.value.getHtml()
  const hasBlock = html.search(`id="someBlock"`) !== -1
  editor.value.BlockManager.get('custom-block').attributes.disable = hasBlock

  editor.value.BlockManager.render();
})
```

Works perfectly.